# Write a program to calculate P(X + Y + Z = k) for arbitrary discrete non-negative rv’s X, Y , and Z

Tags: r

> **Write a program(use R) to calculate P(X + Y + Z = k) for arbitrary discrete non-negative rv’s X, Y , and Z.(rv, random variable)**

This is an exercise from my book. I  have no idea how to start.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this is not a code writing service. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a start**

First, define three different lists, each containing 30 draws from unique binomial distributions (you can define `X`,`Y`, and `Z` as any discrete distribution you want):

```
X = rbinom(30, 10, 0.8)
Y = rbinom(30, 5, 0.5)
Z = rbinom(30, 8, 0.3)
```

Then, create a function that calculates the probability of drawing a certain number `k` from the added lists:

```
probability <- function(k) {
  combine <- X+Y+Z
  return(sum(combine==k)/length(combine))
}
```

An example call with `k=14`:

```
> probability(k=14)
[1] 0.2333333
```